# Galera: replication with SSL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I am setting up a Galera MariaDB cluster. Everything works as expected, unless I turn on SSL. I have 3 nodes, all of them share the same private key and certificate (because I use load balancing as well).

But when I fire up master node with SSL enabled, I get this error from innobackupex:

`Failed to connect to MySQL server: SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1).`

When I run it manually:

```
root@sec-db01:~# innobackupex kkt/
170213 14:18:31 innobackupex: Starting the backup operation

IMPORTANT: Please check that the backup run completes successfully.
       At the end of a successful backup run innobackupex
       prints "completed OK!".

Unrecognized character \x01; marked by <-- HERE after <-- HERE near column 1 at - line 1374.
170213 14:18:31 Connecting to MySQL server host: localhost, user: root, password: set, port: 3306, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Failed to connect to MySQL server: SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1).
```

It seems to me that the problem might be with the certificate - it's connecting to localhost and my certificate is issued to sec-db.mydomain.com - but I have no idea how to get over this.